# Element cannot be clickable even I wait the element clickable for 30 seconds

Tags: java, selenium

I am trying to enter a value in txtStockOnHand field. But, it always throws an error org.openqa.selenium.TimeoutException: Timed out after 30 seconds waiting for element to be clickable: By.id: txtStockOnHand even I wait the element clickable.

Selenium Java Code:

```
@FindBy(how = How.ID, using = "txtStockOnHand")
static WebElement txtStockOnHand;

public void waitForClickable(String strElementID){
    wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By. id(strElementID)));          
}

// Set SOH in SOH textbox
public void setStockOnHand(String strStockOnHand){
    txtStockOnHand.sendKeys(strStockOnHand);
}

public void enterStockOnHand(String strStockOnHand){
    this.waitForClickable("txtStockOnHand");        
    this.setStockOnHand(strStockOnHand);
    txtStockOnHand.sendKeys(Keys.TAB);
}
```

HTML Code:

Answer (score 0):

To solve that problem, I used Thread.sleep method to make the whole thread stop for a while then proceed again after a period of time.

I don't know why wait.until(visibility) and wait.until(clickable) is not functioning somehow.

I hope this help.

```
    // Set SOH in SOH textbox
    public void setStockOnHand(String strStockOnHand){
        try {Thread.sleep(3000);} //3000 for 3 second because it is in millisecond format 
        catch (InterruptedException e) {e.printStackTrace();}
        txtStockOnHand.sendKeys(strStockOnHand);
    }
```

just put it anywhere before you proceed on something else.

You can change the value in sleeptime, you can also put it in a variable :)

## HappyCoding

Comment: I added the thread.sleep(1000) to enterStockOnHand method. It is still not working. It throws the org.openqa.selenium.ElementNotVisibleException: element not visible error.

Comment: where did you put it? before you call the method? or after you call the method right before the txtStockOnHand.sendKeys(strStockOnHand);?

Comment: I bet you have to put it inside the method. Nothing will change if you put it outside the method because selenium will still find element strStockOnHand which is really not yet visible by that time

Comment: Yes, i put it inside the enterStockOnHand method. So, where should I put it? thanks

Comment: I put the try..catch before I call the enterStockOnHand method. It gives me org.openqa.selenium.ElementNotVisibleException: element not visible error

Comment: see my edited answer. change 1000 to 3000 to sure it loads in 3 seconds. or you may observe how much seconds does the element need to be visible. (seconds * 1000) to set milliseconds to seconds.

Answer (score 0):

If Thread.sleep didn't work for you either, I guess it's because several elements in you page have the same id, the first element being hidden. Even if ids are supposed to be unique, I've already faced cases like this.
Can you check if your element's id is really unique?

Comment: My ID is unique. Here is the HTML code:<input class="k-formatted-value fieldFullWidth k-input" tabindex="0" style="display: inline;" title="" aria-disabled="false" aria-readonly="false" type="text">
<input id="txtStockOnHand" class="fieldFullWidth k-input" data-bind="value: selectedAsset.StockOnHand" data-role="numerictextbox" role="spinbutton" style="display: none;" aria-valuenow="0" aria-disabled="false" aria-readonly="false" type="text">